# rewrite and force redirect on rewrite origin url in nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, regex

I have this instance where a html search `<form>` forces it to go to `/search/index.php?q=term` and would like to use something like `/search/term` instead.

This is how the config looks like right now:

```
location /search/ {
    rewrite ^/search/(.+) /search/index.php?q=$1;
}
```

Accessing this location directly works, but in the moment of filling out the form, and searching it will use the "origin" rather than the rewrite.

I tried using redirect "backwards", but that crashed the nginx service:

```
location /search/ {
    rewrite ^/search/(.+) /search/index.php?q=$1;
    redirect ^/search/index.php?q=(.+) /search/$1;
}
```

I also tried rewrite with `permanent` flag, which didn't do anything

```
location /search/ {
    rewrite ^/search/(.+) /search/index.php?q=$1;
    rewrite ^/search/index.php?q=(.+) /search/$1 permanent;
}
```

I know it's possible to achieve the same thing in PHP with something like this:

```
// On the top of /search/index.php
if (str_starts_with($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/index.php')){
    $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == "https") ? "https" : "http";
    $server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $queries = array();
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queries);
    $search = $queries['q'] ?? "";
    header("Location: $protocol://$server/search/$search");
}
```

But think it would be better if nginx could handle this (if it's possible at all).

Does anyone know how to rewrite, and redirect access from the origin ?

Comment: Don't know what the command `redirect` is. But can you show the access log entry for the request that fails?

Comment: @RichardSmith Ok I see, I got that wrong to begin with. I got it from here https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/rewrite-vs-redirect-nginx/ . Nginx systemd log does indeed say it's an unknown directive

Comment: What do you mean by "origin"? Are you saying that the form sends a request to `/search/index.php?...`, and you would like the browser address bar to be changed to `/search/...`?

Comment: Yes, or more specifically: `/search/index.php?q=[term]`, and have it redirected to `/search/[term]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing configuration is something like:

```
location /search/ {
    rewrite ^/search/(.+) /search/index.php?q=$1;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

The URI `/search/index.php` is used internally, so attempting to use `rewrite ^/search/index.php?q=(.+) /search/$1 permanent;` will generate a redirection loop.

To identify the URI as an *external request*, you need to look at the `$request_uri` variable. And for that, you will need to use [the infamous](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) `if` statement. For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/search/index\.php\?q=(.+)) {
    return 301 /search/$1;
}
location /search/ {
    rewrite ^/search/(.+) /search/index.php?q=$1;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I tried putting the if statement inside the scope of `/search/`, but that didn't work. Outside of the scope does work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Indeed, the `/search/index.php` URI is handled by the `location ~ \.php$` block, as it ends in `.php`.

Comment: Ahh! that makes sense, thank you for clarifying

Comment: One can also use `if ($arg_q ~ (.+))` as the `if` condition. It matches only when query argument `q` is non-empty. Using `$request_uri` is not needed.